# Place image over multiple sections in css

Tags: html, css, adobe-xd

[image: Example Image]

I have this image of a long line going over 2 sections in my design file and I would like to translate that with CSS. How should I go about this? should I create a layer that encapsulates both sections with an absolute position?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  --my-orange: rgb(255, 166, 0);
}

.timeline-container {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.timeline-container .timeline {
  width: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--my-orange);
}

.checkpoint {
  border: 3px solid var(--my-orange);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-1.5rem);
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(20vh * var(--i))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timeline-container">
    <div class="timeline">
      <div class="checkpoint" style="--i: 0;">0%</div>
      <div class="checkpoint" style="--i: 1;">5%</div>
      <div class="checkpoint" style="--i: 2;">10%</div>
      <!--more divs-->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```